# How do I turn off anti-aliased brushes in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My brush keeps drawing gray-scales around my lines. I want to remove the gray pixels so I can use the bucket-tool without any problems.

Comment: To think the issue other way around, you could also adjust the `Tolerance` setting of the bucket tool upwards, so it will fill—not only the colour you clicked upon—more of its neighbors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn off anti-aliasing while drawing shapes in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the pencil tool rather than the brush tool to get rid of the grey shades around a line:

[image]

Anti-aliasing actually means you do get the slightly fuzzy edges. Aliasing means that either a black or white value is used as an alias for the true shape - the brush is circular but you can't represent a circle with square pixels. Anti-aliasing attempts to prevent the problem of using either black and white to represent an area the curve passes through by representing this area as a shade of grey.