# How do I preserve hard edges not working in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, anti-aliasing

I want to rotate/warp/resize images but keep all pixels the same color, I don't want soft edges (no antialiasing). I started off with a red square, and rotated it, and it looks like this in the side:

[image]

I want every pixel to be fully opaque red. I went into photoshop cs6 preferences/general and changed the image interpolator to nearest neighbour (hard edges) and restarted photoshop, and then did this, and it looks like the image here....

Does anyone know how to actually do it, or whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to rotate images (normal layers) you need to change the interpolation to nearest neighbor. For shapes and vectors you'll find an anti alias option as explained in here: [How do I turn off anti-aliasing while drawing shapes in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop)

[image: Before rotation]

[image: After rotation]

Comment: I am rotating a rasterized image though.

Comment: Then nearest neighbor it is, I just painted a square in the screenshots, is not a vector.