# Why is it that Photoshop always shows a nice, clean picture when I transform it but when I exit out of transform mode it turns to crap?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I try to edit a photo in Photoshop by just dragging it in, the image is too small so I transform it to make it large enough to fit the screen. It shows a nice picture but whenever I deselect, it looks awful and sharpening tools don't work. I need help. [image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use nearest neighbour interpolation when applying transform. Possible duplicate: [How do I preserve hard edges not working in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58013/how-do-i-preserve-hard-edges-not-working-in-photoshop)

Comment: Raster images lose their quality when they are resized. While the loss of quality is less noticeable when their real size (100% zoom) is reduced, it becomes evident when this size is increased. In this case it is advisable to use the Preserve Details resampling method, that we find in Image > Image Size.

Comment: @spike_66 - "preserve details" won't work well with a pixel art image such as that shown by the OP.  The best interpolation to use in that case is "nearest neighbour" as mentioned by Sergey, and in the duplicate questions.

Comment: @Billy Kerr - in fact I used this method mainly for photos that had to be adapted to larger formats. I thought it could be useful also in this case. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you do ctrl + K, you will open up preferences. You want to change where it says "Image Interpolation" and select nearest neighbor. That will solve the problem.