# Photoshop Single Color for Shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, anti-aliasing

Everytime I use the Ellipse tool in photoshop it creates a border with a black fading to grey outline.

[image]

I want to make an ellipse with a solid black outline with zero gray colors instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an antialiasing issue, if you want perfectly sharp shapes that actually look smooth then please do what you need in illustrator, however, depending on the resolution, you will eventually end up with some grey areas, that is just the way our computer interprets smoothness.

If you still want to have only black spaces, you'll end up with a pixelated look (Unless you work at a really really high resolution ), refer to [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop) for instructions on how to deactivate antialiasing

Comment: Hello El Otmani Ali and welcome to GraphicDesign! Thanks for the contribution. However, we try to avoid answering duplicate questions like this one