# How do I turn off anti-aliasing while drawing shapes in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

This question is asked here: [How do I turn off anti-aliasing while drawing shapes in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop)

And it has an answer from almost a decade ago. Photoshop has changed a lot then.

How do you do this in Photoshop CC?

Comment: I think, unless you are more specific, this is a duplicate of the question you liked to. I'd vote to close it as such, but that would close it immediately. Photoshop has really *not* changed in this respect. There's no global setting to enable/disable anti-aliasing in Photoshop. The nature of a pixel-based editor is to anti-alias. Other than using "Nearest Neighbor" when scaling, there's not really much there.

Answer (score 1):

There's no antialiasing settings in Photoshop for shapes, but there's a trick suppressing the antialiasing in an action.

[image: antialiasing action]

---

### Indexing a file

By transforming the RGB document into Indexed with the palette of your operating system you can use the **Shape Tool** without antialiasing.

[image: Indexed doc]

### Setting a transparent color

An indexed document does not support layers, but transparency.

From the menu **Image** > **Mode** > **Color Table**, click on a random color holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and this color will become transparent.

Select all and click <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> Win to make the document transparent. When creating a new shape this will be on a transparent background.

[image: transparent background]

### Implementing the previous steps in a RGB document

From the menu **Image** > **Mode** > **Color Table**, save the custom palette with the transparent color.

Working from an RGB document, once the shape is made:

- Convert the shape into a **Smart Object**
- Double click to edit it
- Convert it into an indexed file with the saved palette
- Convert it back to a RGB file
- Save and close to update it to the original RGB file

In this way you have the same shape without antialiasing. This process is a single click in an **action**.

[image: Action]

Apply a **Color Overlay** effect to change the Smart Object color.

[image: Color Overlay]

Comment: Great. A Threshold Layer in Lighter mode with a little lower threshold level does the trick also.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is a real pain in the ass, because I need to convert all my custom drawing vector shapes into turned off antialiasing. I am glad that this feature is still available for text. I need to design a GUI for a lower-quality screen. Is there some other tool that can easily convert all my custom shapes and supports importing SVG files?